# How to get the mean for each group in pandas.dataframe like seaborn.factorplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataset formatted as a pandas dataframe. Please see this example in seaborn http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.factorplot.html#seaborn.factorplot

```
>>> import seaborn as sns
>>> sns.set(style="ticks")
>>> exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
>>> g = sns.factorplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)
```

With sns.factorplot, I can see the mean of the data by group (for this instance, the chart shows the mean of pulse at 1/15/30 mins group by the "kind").

I want to directly get the "values" in the chart.
For example

```
time      kind     mean    standard deviation
1 min     running  xx      xx
15 min    running  xx      xx
```

I can use 2-depth loop to get the value I want, but I think there should be something easyier in pandas since it is a common requirement.

Different from matplotlib, which will return all the values in the plot, seaborn returns a Facetgrid object. It seems that Facetgrid do not have the data I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by columns `time` and `kind` and [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) `mean` and `std`:

```
print (exercise.groupby(['time','kind'])['pulse'].agg(['mean', 'std']))
#agg same as aggregate, only less typing ;)
#print (exercise.groupby(['time','kind'])['pulse'].aggregate(['mean', 'std']))
                 mean        std
time   kind                     
1 min  rest      90.2   6.545567
       walking   93.1   6.297266
       running   96.1   4.483302
15 min rest      90.9   6.118279
       walking   96.6   7.441625
       running  117.1  12.991023
30 min rest      91.4   5.337498
       walking   95.9   6.740425
       running  126.0  16.964014
```

---

```
df1 = exercise.groupby(['time','kind'])['pulse'].agg(['mean', 'std']).reset_index()
print (df1)
     time     kind   mean        std
0   1 min     rest   90.2   6.545567
1   1 min  walking   93.1   6.297266
2   1 min  running   96.1   4.483302
3  15 min     rest   90.9   6.118279
4  15 min  walking   96.6   7.441625
5  15 min  running  117.1  12.991023
6  30 min     rest   91.4   5.337498
7  30 min  walking   95.9   6.740425
8  30 min  running  126.0  16.964014
```

Comment: Yeah, that's actually what I want. Thank you very much.